# magento 1.9 Which layout XML file specifies which list.phtml file will show a list of subcategories within a category?

Tags: php, xml, magento

I want to specify a different list.phtml for showing subcategories within a category when clicking through categories from the list.phtml used to showcase a list of products.

I have one list.phtml that works great for listing subcategories, but then messes up placement of the shopping cart/shopping cart items when showing products.

I have another list.phtml that works great for listing products inside of a category, but doesn't show subcategories of a category when you click on it.

My goal is to specify a different list.phtml for when you are viewing a list of subcategories, from when you are viewing a list of products inside a layout XML file if that is possible.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can set different layout from admin for category. To set different `list.phtml` for parent category you can follow below steps-

1. In Admin panel Create a static block (from **CMS-> static blocks**)
2. In static block you can add your `list.phtml` for sub categories using below code

   {{block type="core/template" template="path/to/your/file/list.phtml"}} // You can replace core/template with your **module/block**
3. Now go to **Catalog->Manage Categories**
4. Select the parent category for which you want to display subcategory list
5. Now select **Display settings** tab
6. Now select **Static block only** in **Display Mode**
7. And Select your block from in **CMS Block** dropdown
8. Clean cache and check the category pages in frontend

**Note**: don't forget to add your custom module/block to whitelist from **System->Permissions->Blocks**